# What is the origin of the word assassin?

Tags: etymology, latin, arabic, italian

I discussed this recently with some friends and different explanations regarding the words etymology were mentioned. I did some research and confirmed these two:

1. from Arab. aššāšīn "hashish eater" (pl.), to arab. ašīš "herbs, weeds, hemp plant, hashish",  Member of a political-religious Islamic sect in the medieval. The sect's founder had his followers drink a hashed potion to make them compliant for the murders he ordered
2. from Italian - Assassinare, which literally means to kill someone. Furthermore it was mentioned by a friend that this word originated from latin and meant back then something like "throwing a stone at someone" - I could not find anything in this direction

Does anybody know which background is the original one?

Comment: assassinare comes from Arabic aššāšīn, not from Latin or anything to do with stones

Comment: Well, actually it is ḥaššāšiyyīn.

Comment: ........حشاشيين

Comment: So does that mean, that the italian word assasinare occurred from arabic?

Comment: @MatthiasMohr Yes, it was [an Islamic sect that Europeans encountered during Crusader times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_Assassins). They were known for targeting and quietly killing high-ranking members of enemy factions, and so gave their name to the practice of assassination in European languages who heard reports of them.

Answer (score 5):

The origin appears to come from the name of the Nizari Ismaili state founded by Hassan-i Sabbah who termed his followers Asāsiyyūn [أساسيون](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%8A#Arabic), the root of which translates as "fundamentals". Marco Polo is credited with confusing that term with "hashish" الحشيش. A subset of the members of the sect, the فِدائيّين‎ fidāʼīyīn, engaged in military actions such as "assassination".

Comment: A most dubious conjecture.

Comment: These assassins also engaged in the consumption of hashish, popular legend has it. Popularized by Robert A. Wilson, I believe.

Comment: This answer needs citations

Comment: The Marco Polo one is sourced on Wikipedia; the etymology of Asāsiyyūn isn't but should presumably be clear to an Arabic speaker. Many words related to *foundation* certainly have the consonants of ﺃَﺳَﺎﺱ *ʔasaas* as their root (but verifying the etymology of this particular one is beyond my knowledge).